# Avoid statements inside if statements raising errors when false bash

Tags: bash, if-statement, error-handling

To keep my data in structured form I often end up having deep folder-trees where it can be a little annoying going back and forward in so I wrote a function to generate an html tree of the cwd:

```
function toc_date {

   # Get the date in _YYYY-MM-DD format
   D=`date +_%F`

   # Build the tree, -H flag to output as HTML, 
   # . to use current dir in <a href> link

   tree -H . >> toc$D.html

}
```

The problem arose when I wrote a follow up function to remove old folder-tree files, specifically in the first expr of `[ "$(ls -b toc_* | wc -l)" -gt "0" ]` which gives an error when no files are found even though it's value is correctly set to 0, which should make it skip the if statement (right?). The code works as intended, but error messages are usually not a sign of good code, so was hoping that someone might be able to suggest improvements?

```
function old_stuff {

   # Number of lines i.e. files matching toc_*   
   if [ "$(ls -b toc_* | wc -l)" -gt "0" ]  
   then 
       # Show files/directories so we don't remove stuff unintended    
       ls toc_*

       while true; do
               read -p "Do you wish to remove old TOCs? [Y/n]" yn
               case $yn in
                   [Nn]* ) break;;
                   [Yy]* ) rm toc_*; break;;
                   * ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
               esac
        done
   fi
   # Go ahead and generate the html tree 
   toc_date 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to:

```
if [ "$(ls -b toc_* 2>/dev/null | wc -l)" -gt "0" ]
```

Another slightly more readable and better way is (stripped off unnecessary quotes):

```
if [ $(ls | grep -c '^toc_') -gt 0 ]
```

Comment: Thanks! I especially like the second option as it circumvent the ls "no such file or directory" error, rather than redirecting it.

Answer (score 0):

just an advice , take this out`"$(ls -b toc_* | wc -l)"` and set it inside a variable

```
fileCount=$(ls -b toc_* 2>/dev/null | wc -l)
```

The `2>/dev/null` is to send stderr i.e any kind of error message to /dev/null

And also it is advisable you always use `[[ ]]` whenever you are writing an if statement, to avoid errors like `unary operator is expected`